# I changed my code but it dosen't show the seconds counting down why?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the JavaScript code I use now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
      var counter = 7000;
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              counter = setInterval(displayNextImage, counter);
              var count = 60;
              count = count - 1;
              if (count == -1) {
                  clearInterval(counter);
                  return;
              }

              counter = count % 60;
              var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
              var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
              minutes %= 60;
              hours %= 60;
              document.getElementById("startTimer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update.";
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000116.Gif";
          images[1] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radarClosed.gif";
      </script>
      <br><br><span id="startTimer"></span><br><br>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

The variable counter is global set to 7 seconds.
When i'm loading my website it does changing the images every 7 seconds.

But i want to show in the timer to display on the website the 7 seconds ocunting back.
This time it's 7 seconds but if i set counter to for example 50000 then it should count back 5 minutesand show each time also the seconds counting back.

1. How do i make it to work with one global variable counter ?
2. How can i make it to work also if i will use 3 global variable for hours minutes seconds ?

In both way the result should be the same to display the counter counting back untill the next image.
And places in my code that are repeated i will fix it later but first i want it to work at all.

EDIT

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          //init vars, 0 hours 0 minutes and 7 seconds.
//alter the times as you need.
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 7;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

function initTimer() {

    //init the counter according to the required times:
    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    //this sets a timer to fire ever 1000 milliseconds - aka 1 second.
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function switcher() {
    //decrease the timers and init the swap if timer reaches 0.
    down_counter_seconds--;
    //first condition is the stop condition, if counter reaches 0:
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        //do the swapping
        swapColor();
        //restart the counter:
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    }
    //second condition, if seconds =0 but minutes >0
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        //decrease one minute
        down_counter_seconds = 60;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    //third condition, if minutes =0 but hours > 0
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        //decrease one hour
        down_counter_minutes = 60;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }
    //eventually, output the counter time:
    document.getElementById("div_hours").innerText = down_counter_hours;
    document.getElementById("div_minutes").innerText = down_counter_minutes;
    document.getElementById("div_seconds").innerText = down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    displayNextImage();
}

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000116.Gif";
          images[1] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radarClosed.gif";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "initTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, a few things:

- you cant set both a number and a timeout function to the same variable. use separate varaibles.
- dont use `setInterval` if you are going to clear it every time. user `setTimeout` it will fire only one time.
- if you are going to reset it every time, better set a `setInterval` and dont clear it, let it run and just manipulate counters while its running.

<kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/f9tbznqm/)**</kbd>

```
//init vars, 0 hours 0 minutes and 7 seconds.
//alter the times as you need.
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 7;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

document.onload = initTimer();

function initTimer() {

    //init the counter according to the required times:
    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    //this sets a timer to fire ever 1000 milliseconds - aka 1 second.
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function switcher() {
    //decrease the timers and init the swap if timer reaches 0.
    down_counter_seconds--;
    //first condition is the stop condition, if counter reaches 0:
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        //do the swapping
        swapColor();
        //restart the counter:
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    }
    //second condition, if seconds =0 but minutes >0
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        //decrease one minute
        down_counter_seconds = 59;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    //third condition, if minutes =0 but hours > 0
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        //decrease one hour
        down_counter_minutes = 59;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }
    //eventually, output the counter time:
    document.getElementById("div_hours").innerText = down_counter_hours;
    document.getElementById("div_minutes").innerText = down_counter_minutes;
    document.getElementById("div_seconds").innerText = down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    //do your changes here
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("div_switcher");
    if (myDiv.style["background"] == "red") {
        myDiv.style["background"] = "blue"
    } else {
        myDiv.style["background"] = "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Banana i tried to use your solution in my code but it's not working. I guess i didn't do it right. Could you look what i did and show me how to fix it ? I added my code to the question.

Comment: can you please be more specific about how its not working correctly? seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/0trzh854/

Comment: Yes it does working the same for me too but it's not showing the timer it self. also in your link for jsfiddle i see the images change but i wanted above the images to see the timer counting 7 seconds back or if it's 7 minutes then 7 minutes back untill the next image change. For example above the images to see: Hours: 00 Minutes: 00 Seconds: 00 or maybe in other format and see the timer count back to the next image.

Comment: oh, well you need to output the timer into an element, in my example i output the timer in 3 divs `div_hours/minutes/seconds`, however you did not add those divs in your html...